# How to test fs.writeFile errors with mocha + chai + sinon

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, sinon, chai

I would like to test that if an error happens during `fs.writeFile` a message is output to the console log. The below test do pass, but it outputs the stack trace of the error to the testing console, which is unwanted. How to avoid that?

```
describe('with fs error', () => {
  it('should output errors to console', () => {
    sandbox.stub(fs, 'writeFile').yields(new Error('write error'));
    const consoleSpy = sandbox.spy(console, 'log');
    history.save();
    expect(consoleSpy).to.have.been.calledOnce;
  });
});
```

Comment: I suppose I want to test on the exact error message too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not ideal, but if you stub `console.log` and immediately restore it after calling `history.save`, you probably won't interfere with Mocha's use of `console.log`:

```
it('should output errors to console', () => {
  sandbox.stub(fs, 'writeFile').yields(new Error('write error'));
  const consoleStub = sinon.stub(console, 'log');
  history.save();
  consoleStub.restore();
  expect(consoleStub).to.have.been.calledOnce;
});
```

To test if the correct error was thrown:

```
it('should output the correct error to console', () => {
  let error = new Error('write error');
  sandbox.stub(fs, 'writeFile').yields(error);
  const consoleStub = sinon.stub(console, 'log');
  history.save();
  consoleStub.restore();
  expect(consoleStub).to.have.been.calledWith(error);
});
```